# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request in Python function

Tags: python, function, python-3.5, urllib, beautifulsoup

I am making a program which searches for recipes based on certain input (being ingredients so far). The program works when I search for only a few ingredients, but a few more return an urllib error. I looked at other questions but they were for urllib 2 and their solutions didn't fix my issue.

Link where it works (searching for a few ingredients) - http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?ingIncl=Chicken&ingExcl=beef&sort=re

Link where it doesn't (searching for more) - http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?ingIncl=chicken,cheese,egg&ingExcl=lettuce&sort=re

*My code below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request


html = "http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?ingIncl='chicken', 'cheese', 'egg'&ingExcl='lettuce'&sort=re"
number = 5



def get_recipes(html, number):######## this doesnt work if there are a few ingredients

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(html)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    num_results = soup.find('span',{'class': 'subtext'}).get_text()
    num_results = str(number) + ' out of ' + num_results #number will have to be changed if less recipes were found than number

    i = 0
    recipe_dict = {}


    for card in soup.find_all('article', {'class':'grid-col--fixed-tiles'}): #gets 2 more than required
        try: 
            info = card.find('a', {'data-internal-referrer-link':'hub recipe'})
            link = info.get('href')
            name = info.get_text()
            recipe_dict[name] = link
            if i > (number - 2): #-2 is temp fix
                break
            else:
                i += 1
        except:
            pass
    print(recipe_dict)
    return recipe_dict

get_recipes(html, number)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Diet Buddy\DB_find_recipes.py", line 39, in <module>
    get_recipes(html, number)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Diet Buddy\DB_find_recipes.py", line 13, in get_recipes
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(html)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a simple typo.  Compare:

```
html = "http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?ingIncl='chicken', 'cheese', 'egg'&ingExcl='lettuce'&sort=re"
```

And

```
html = "http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?ingIncl=chicken,cheese,egg&ingExcl=lettuce&sort=re"
```